# Adding condition in where conditionally

Tags: mysql, if-statement, conditional-statements, where-clause

I can't seem to find a proper solution for this. Here's  the scenario I want to
add a condition if the parameter is 0. Looks something like

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE  name = @name AND 
//this is the part I dont know but I want something like
IF(@id = 0)
{
//do nothing
}else{
id = @id
}
```

Comment: You probaby want a `CASE` but is hard to guess with so little info Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MySQL, `IF` is a function (it's like the ternary operator in C and PHP). You can return `TRUE` from it in the case where you don't need to do anything.

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE name = @name
AND IF(@id = 0, TRUE, id = @id)
```

Another way to do it is with `OR`:

```
WHERE name = @name AND (@id = 0 OR id = @id)
```